# Помогите с множеством при парсинге на Python!

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Пишу парсер на Python. Уже написан парсинг курса валют. Всё прекрасно работает. Однако при попытке парсить курс какой-либо акции выдаётся ошибка.

```
#ENPG
ENPG = 'https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01B_tUfRT69P1gXaIazqzSucN1Pyg%3A1598475708654&ei=vM1GX8ufJ-2GwPAPsYe0wAQ&q=акции+enpg&oq=акции+enpg&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQDTIGCAAQDRAeMgYIABANEB46BwgjELECECc6BggAEAcQHjoICAAQBxAKEB46BwgjELACECc6CAgAEAgQBxAeOggIABAHEAUQHjoGCAAQCBAeOggIABAIEA0QHjoFCAAQzQJQ8KMJWKTBCWCewwloAHAAeACAAXeIAaMLkgEEMTcuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjL7a6G4rnrAhVtAxAIHbEDDUgQ4dUDCA0&uact=5'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_16_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.86 YaBrowser/20.8.0.893 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}
full_page = requests.get(ENPG, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
convert_enpg = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "IsqQVc", "class": "NprOob", "data-precision": 2})

lbl3 = Label(window, text="EN+GROUP" + convert_enpg[0].text, font=("Arial Bold", 15), background='LightCyan')
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/ilyas/Desktop/programming/python/SafinInvest/main.py", line 35, in  lbl3 = Label(window, text="EN+GROUP" + convert_enpg[0].text, font=("Arial Bold", 15), background='LightCyan')
> IndexError: list index out of range

**IndexError: list index out of range** Я только начинаю изучать Python, делаю свой проект просто ради интереса. Как я понял, ошибка в том, что импортируется не некое множество информации, а один пункт. Однако, когда я убираю из 35-й строки *[0]*, то появляется другая ошибка.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/ilyas/Desktop/programming/python/SafinInvest/main.py", line 35, in 
> lbl3 = Label(window, text="EN+GROUP" + convert_enpg.text, font=("Arial Bold", 15), background='LightCyan')
> File "/Users/ilyas/Desktop/programming/python/SafinInvest/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2160, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError(
> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Мне кажется, ошибка при обращении `convert_enpg[0]`. Если у него нет хотя бы одного элемента - то будет ошибка (нельзя взять первый элемент из путого множества). Попробуйте проверить, есть ли у что-то в `convert_enpg` перед 35-ой строкой.

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена! Просто убрал data-precision